# RegExp to validate URL with port or IP with PORT (JS)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a robust RegExp that validates URL with port or IP with PORT e.g

http://123.456.78.900:4200 > true

http://something:4200 > true

I searched but didn't find an expression that checks both

```
isUrlValid(input) {
  const regex = '^((https:|http:|[/][/]|www.)([a-z]|[A-Z]|[:0-9]|[/.])*)$'​;
  const url = new RegExp(regex, 'g');
  return url.test(input);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this**

```
^((https?:\/\/)|(www.))(?:([a-zA-Z]+)|(\d+\.\d+.\d+.\d+)):\d{4}$
```

- `^` - Anchor to start of string.
- `((https?:\/\/)|(www.))` -Matches `http://` or `https://` or `www.`.
- `(?:([a-zA-Z]+)|(\d+\.\d+.\d+.\d+))`

  - `?:`- Makes group non-capturing.
  - `([a-zA-Z]+)`- Matches any alphabets one or more time (add 0-9 if you want digits too).
  - `|` : Alternation works as logical OR.
  - `(\d+\.\d+.\d+.\d+)`- Matches digit format for IP address.
- `:\d{4}` - Will match 4 digit number this you can adjust as per your use case.
- `$` - Anchor to end of string.

[click here for demo](https://regex101.com/r/YmVBNH/5)

**P.S** - For performance you can make groups as non-capturing group by using `?:` at start. i intentionally not added them for the sake of readability.

Comment: Port number can have 1 to 5 digits. I think `{1,5}` would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+:\d*
```

Your second domain not contains dot for this case - i have this

```
^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)*:\d*
```

Comment: That doesn't match `http://something:4200` :P It _does_ match `http://123.456.78.900:foobar`, which also seems wrong.

Comment: I fix my answer